# How to persist document tab order when using EnableMDITabbedGroups in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, tabs, mfc

VS2010 with an MDI document layout using tabs along the top to switch between documents.  Each document is a "live" view into a database, where the persistent data per document is a group of configuration settings.

We would like to allow the user to rearrange the tabs (this functionality is built in), but need to persist this new order. Right now it appears the document z-order is not affected by moving the tabs around.  when closing the app, the documents close in the order they were opened so this is not helpful in determining the final tab order on close.

We are using the `EnableMDITabbedGroups(TRUE, mdiTabParams)` with `m_bEnableTabSwap = TRUE` which is the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks! Ended up with the following solution in the MainFrame::OnClose() method.

Note that this code example uses two custom classes of 1) CSpectraAnalysisUtilityView which inherits from CView and 2) CReviewDataFolder which is our object that we needed to update the recent Tab Order.

This code solution also implements the GetMDITabGroups in case there are multiple group windows open.

```
void CMainFrame::OnClose()
{
    iReviewDataFolderOrder = 1;

    const CObList& tabGroups =m_wndClientArea.GetMDITabGroups(); 
    if (0 < tabGroups.GetCount())
    { 
        POSITION pos = tabGroups.GetHeadPosition(); 
        CMFCTabCtrl* pCrtTabCtrl;

        while(pos != NULL) 
        { 
            pCrtTabCtrl=DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCTabCtrl, tabGroups.GetNext(pos)); 

            int count = pCrtTabCtrl->GetTabsNum();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {   
                CWnd* pWnd = pCrtTabCtrl->GetTabWndNoWrapper(i); 
                CMDIChildWnd *pChild = ((CMDIChildWnd*)(pWnd));
                if (pChild)
                {
                    CView *pView = pChild->GetActiveView();
                    if (pView)
                    {
                        if (pView->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSpectraAnalysisUtilityView)))
                        {
                            CSpectraAnalysisUtilityView* specUtilView;

                            specUtilView = (CSpectraAnalysisUtilityView*)pView;
                            CReviewDataFolder* pDataFolder = specUtilView->GetSpecReviewDataFolder();
                            if(pDataFolder)
                            {
                                pDataFolder->SetRecentOrder(iReviewDataFolderOrder);
                                iReviewDataFolderOrder++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    CMDIFrameWnd::OnClose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Upon destruction of the outer main frame (`OnDestroy`) you can access the the `CMFCTabCtrl` members and can loop over each tab and determine the current sequence stored in the tab. `GetTabWnd` will allow you to access each tab by its index.

To access the tab control use `CMDIClientAreaWnd::GetMDITab`.